# What's new in WebPages and Razor 3.1.2

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

Can't find information about v3.1.2
Look for on https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/
Any known? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mainly bug fixes. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc.aspx

> **ASP.NET MVC 5.1.2, ASP.NET Web API 2.1.2 and ASP.NET Web Pages 3.1.2 are included**
>
> We announced ASP.NET MVC 5.1, ASP.NET Web API 2.1 and ASP.NET Web
>   Pages 3.1 in January.  We integrated that release with some minor
>   5.1.1 bug fixes into VS 2013 Update 2 RC. 5.1.2 contains the same binaries plus localization for IntelliSense usage.

Answer (score 1):

On [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/releases/whats-new-aspnet-web-pages-31) they say "*ASP.NET Web Pages 3.1.0 contains several bug fixes. You can find the complete list [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?keyword=&status=Closed&type=All&priority=All&release=v5.1%20Preview%7Cv5.1%20RTM&assignedTo=All&component=Web%20Pages/Razor&sortField=AssignedTo&sortDirection=Ascending&page=0&reasonClosed=Fixed).*" and "***The ASP.NET Web Pages 3.1.1 package does not contain any changes***. The package version number was updated to match the versions of MVC and Web API."